# Eliminate $\theta$ from the equations $x=\cos 2\theta$ and $y=\sec\theta$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, parametric

Help for this question please. Can't figure it out and can only find examples of $\sin$ and $\cos$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Use that $\cos 2\theta = \cos^2\theta - \sin^2\theta = 2\cos^2\theta - 1$, and so $$\cos 2\theta = 2\frac{1}{\sec^2\theta}-1.$$Plug in $x$ and $y$ where you must and be happy.